# css style loading + id. eg loading1, loading300

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this in css:

> ```
> #loading{
> display:none;
> }
> ```

the problem is, i need to display none this loading div, that come with an id after loading name.

eg:

> ```
> <div id=loading1></div>
> <div id=loading422></div>
> <div id=loading9232></div>
> ```

I want to apply loading style in all this divs, can i do that? how would it be?

thank you!

Comment: use class instead of id?

.loading and div class"loading"

Comment: what is the difference between class and id?

Comment: @renatacosta: An `id` has to be unique to the element (there can only be one element with that value). A *class* lets an element belong to a group (or "class") of other elements with which it has things in common. So `<div id="foo">...</div>` is the only foo, but `<div class="foo">...</div>` could be one of several elements with the `foo` class. You can then style those elements like this: `.foo { /* ... */ }`. More: [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), [`class`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to apply loading style in all this divs, can i do that?

Yes, with an [*attribute starts with selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
[id^=loading] {
    display: none;
}
```

That matches any element whose `id` attribute *starts with* `loading`.

---

Example:

```css
[id^=loading] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading1">loading1</div>
<div id="loading12">loading12</div>
<div id="loading123">loading123</div>
<div id="notloading">notloading, so not affected</div>
<div id="loading">loading with nothing after</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div[id^=loading]{display:none;}
```

Refer [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more details

**Examples:**

```
/* All spans with a "lang" attribute are bold */
 span[lang] {
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* All spans in Portuguese are green */
 span[lang="pt"] {
    color:green;
}
/* All spans in US English are blue  */
 span[lang~="en-us"] {
    color: blue;
}
/* Any span in Chinese is red, matches simplified (zh-CN) or traditional (zh-TW) */
 span[lang|="zh"] {
    color: red;
}
/* All internal links have a gold background */
 a[href^="#"] {
    background-color:gold
}
/* All links to urls ending in ".cn" are red */
 a[href$=".cn"] {
    color: red;
}
/* All links to with "example" in the url have a grey background */
 a[href*="example"] {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello  freind  you  can  put  an  class  attribut  and name it loading
like  this

```
<div id=loading1 class="loading"></div>
<div id=loading422 class="loading"></div>
<div id=loading9232 class="loading"></div>
```

and  call  it  in your  css like this

```
.loading{
display:none;
}
```

that's can be  better  than id  class  is  good

i hope  to  find that  is  helpfull